# Is there an easy way to use an OSGi bundle in a classpath for Ant junit or java tasks?

Tags: ant, classpath, osgi

I have a bunch of OSGi bundles that are basically jars that contain other jars and a manifest.

```
bundle xyz.jar:
   somejar1.jar
   somejar2.jar
   Manifest
```

I want to run some junit tests, and need some classes inside these bundles.  Is there an easy way in Ant to say

`<path name="myclasspath" location="[stuff inside OSGI bundle xyz.jar]>`  ?

I could unjar these to a temp directory, but that seems tedious, plus I would not be leveraging the classpath inside the OSGi bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not a problem if you're using ant to run PDE build/OSGi application, OSGi would handle with the classpath.

Comment: ahh, but this isn't for a build.   I've got some ant scripts doing automation-type stuff, and for a particular task I just want the classpath scraped from a bundle.  But maybe I can pull something out of PDE to get this info.  Thanks!